How to Prevent Excessive Re-renders in Dynamic Forms Using React Hook Form and Material-UI?
I'm developing a dynamic form with React Hook Form and Material-UI where the content changes based on the first two user selections. My setup includes a "Generator" page that renders different form configurations based on these selections. However, I'm encountering performance issues as the entire Generator component re-renders whenever an input value changes.
Here's a simplified outline of my setup:

formConfiguration: Always visible and does not change.
combinedConfigurations: Changes based on initial user choices.
Generator: Renders forms based on the configuration.
Each input modification triggers a re-render of the Generator, as indicated by a console.log('generator') call.

I have attempted using useMemo and useCallback to optimize performance but the issue persists.
Here’s my generator page
//all my import...

export const Generator = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const methods = useForm({
    defaultValues: { 
      createdBy: 'User one',
    },
  });

  const step = useSelector((state) => state.step.actual);
  const customers = useSelector((state) => state.customer.customers);
 
  const customerUsers = useSelector((state) => state.customer?.contacts);
  const categories = useSelector((state) => state.categories?.categories);
  const services = useSelector((state) => state.services?.services);
  const regions = useSelector((state) => state.regions?.regions);
  const stacks = useSelector((state) => state.stacks?.stacks);
  const profiles = useSelector((state) => state.profiles?.profiles);
  const articles = useSelector((state) => state.articles?.articles);


  const category = methods.watch('category');
  const service = methods.watch('service');
  const region = methods.watch('region');
  const customer = methods.watch('customer');

  const mergeFormConfigurations = (baseConfig, additionalConfig) => {
    return { ...baseConfig, ...additionalConfig };
  };

  const getFormConfiguration = () => {
    let combinedConfigurations = formConfiguration(
      category,
      customers, 
      categories,
      services,
      customerUsers,
      regions
    );

    if (service?.name === 'Consultancy') {
      combinedConfigurations = mergeFormConfigurations(
        combinedConfigurations,
        consultancyFormConfiguration(stacks, profiles)
      );
    }
    if (service?.name === 'New support contract') {
      combinedConfigurations = mergeFormConfigurations(
        combinedConfigurations,
        newSupportContractFormConfiguration(articles)
      );
    }
    if (service?.name === 'Refill support contract') {
      combinedConfigurations = mergeFormConfigurations(
        combinedConfigurations,
        refillSupportContractFormConfiguration(articles, region)
      );
    }
    return combinedConfigurations;
  };

  const currentFormConfiguration = getFormConfiguration();

  const FormWrapper = ({ step, methods }) => {
    console.log('FormWrapper');

    const configuration = currentFormConfiguration[step];
    if (!configuration) {
      return null;
    }

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
      const newData = { ...data, articles };
      postOffer(newData);
    };

    const test = methods.watch();
    return (
      <Box>
        <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <NewOffer />
          <Save />

          <FormComponent
            title={configuration.title}
            InputFields={configuration.InputFields}
          />
        </form>
      </Box>
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setLocation('generator'));
     dispatch(getCategories());
    dispatch(getRegions());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    region && dispatch(getCustomers(1, region));
  }, [region]);

  useEffect(() => {
    category && dispatch(getServices(category?.category_id));
  }, [category]);

  useEffect(() => {
    customer && dispatch(getCustomerContacts(customer.customerId));
  }, [customer]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (service)
      switch (service.name) {
        case 'Consultancy': {
          dispatch(getStacks());
          dispatch(getProfiles());
          break;
        }
        case 'New support contract': {
          dispatch(getArticlesByService('support', 'new'));
          break;
        }
        case 'Refill support contract': {
          dispatch(getArticlesByService('support', 'refill'));
          break;
        }
        default:
          break;
      }
  }, [service, region]);

  console.log('generator');
  return (
    <Box>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <StepsBar />
        <FormWrapper step={step} methods={methods} />
      </FormProvider>
    </Box>
  );
};

Then a Form configuration exemple :
export const formConfiguration = (
  categoryChoice,
  customers, 
  categories,
  services,
  customerUsers,
  regions
) => {
  return {
    Category: {
      title: 'Category',
      InputFields: [
        {
          pieTitle: 'Category',
          inputType: 'pie',
          register: 'category',
          Size: 500,
          datas: categories,
        },
      ],
    },
    Services: {
      title: 'Services',
      InputFields: [
        {
          pieTitle: 'Services catalog',
          inputType: 'pie',
          register: 'service',
          Size: 500,
          datas: services,
        },
      ],
    },
    'Informations générales': {
      title: 'Informations générales',
      InputFields: [
        {
          inputType: 'radio',
          inputTitle: 'Sélectionnez la region concernée',
          options: regions,
          optionLabel: 'code',
          optionValue: 'code',
          register: 'region',
        },
        {
          inputType: 'mask',
          inputLabel: 'N° DEVIS',
          inputTitle: 'Numéro de devis',
          mask: 'DEV-99-9999',
          register: 'dev',
          defaultValue: 'DEV-XX-XXXX',
        },
        {
          inputType: 'text',
          inputLabel: 'Référence',
          inputTitle: 'Votre référence',
          register: 'reference',
          type: 'text',
        }
      ],
    },
  };
};

then I use the fields configuration here
export const FormComponent = ({ title, InputFields }) => {
  console.log(InputFields, 'FormComponent');
  return (
    <Box>
      <Typography variant="h4">{title}</Typography>

      {InputFields?.map((el) => (
        <InputField infos={el} />
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
};

The Input switch
//all import

export const InputField = ({ infos }) => {
  switch (infos?.inputType) {
    case 'radio':
      return <Radio infos={infos} />;
    case 'text':
      return <Text infos={infos} />;
    case 'mask':
      return <Mask infos={infos} />;
    case 'pie':
      return <PieChart infos={infos} />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

and then a input
export const Text = ({ infos }) => {
  const { register } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
      <FormLabel>{infos?.inputTitle}</FormLabel>
      <TextField
        label={infos?.inputLabel}
        type={infos?.type}
        {...register(infos?.register, infos?.registerParams)}
      />
    </Box>
  );
};

Could using useMemo or useCallback be the right approach to prevent these re-renders, or should I consider restructuring my components? Any suggestions on how to improve the structure or the use of hooks in this scenario would be greatly appreciated.
Update : When I remove the global watch present in FormWrapper, the bug and the logs disappear. This is a temporary solution I have found.
It sounds like the global watch was triggering too many re-renders in the FormWrapper.
It's seems that the error come from FormWrapper and currentFormConfiguration with step

I simplified the structure by removing FormWrapper and integrating its logic directly into Generator. This approach reduced the number of re-renders by avoiding unnecessary state updates between the parent and child components.
export const Generator = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const methods = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      createdBy: 'test',
    },
  });

  const step = useSelector((state) => state.step.actual);
  const articles = useSelector((state) => state.articles?.articles);
  const currentFormConfiguration = methods.watch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setLocation('generator'));
    dispatch(getCategories());
    dispatch(getRegions());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    methods.getValues('region') && dispatch(getCustomers(1, methods.getValues('region')));
  }, [methods.watch('region')]);

  useEffect(() => {
    methods.getValues('category') && dispatch(getServices(methods.getValues('category')?.category_id));
  }, [methods.watch('category')]);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const newData = { ...data, articles };
    postOffer(newData);
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <StepsBar />
        <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <FormComponent
            title={currentFormConfiguration[step].title}
            InputFields={currentFormConfiguration[step].InputFields}
          />
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </Box>
  );
};

